# d3.max() not returning the max value in an array?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've been teaching myself d3 overnight and can't seem to figure out this one issue I am having. I am dynamically feeding the `d3.max()` method an array of numbers (I have tried parsing them with `parseInt()`/`parseFloat()` as well as not parsing them) through an HTML `<select>` element. I am using the console to check the values as my visualizations are becoming skewed. However, sometimes it does return the max value, and sometimes it just doesn't.

```
var localityElectricityConsumption = localities[localityName].totalElectricityConsumption;
            maxConsumption = d3.max(localityElectricityConsumption);
            r = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxConsumption]).range([120, 0]);

            console.log("array being fed to d3.max: " + localityElectricityConsumption);
            console.log("what d3.max() is returning: " + d3.max(localityElectricityConsumption));
            console.log("what parseInt(d3.max()) is returning: " + d3.max(localityElectricityConsumption));
```

You can see the live visualization and check the console [here](https://in-info-web4.informatics.iupui.edu/~brjebrow/N328/assignment3/). Try using the top-most graph to switch from the North American locality to the Mexico locality. `d3.max()` returns the max value for North America, but not Mexico, and therefore doesn't graph the data correctly for Mexico. I am officially stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here is the code that is used to create `localities[localityName].totalElectricityConsumption`:

```
 d3.csv("data/" + dataset, function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var record = data[i];

                if (dataset === "total_electricity_consumption.csv") {
                    currentDataset = listOfDatasets[0].name;
                    record.totalElectricityConsumption = [];

                    // loop through all years, from 1980 to 2012
                    for (var year = 1980; year <= 2012; year++) {
                        var value = record[year];

                        // deal with missing data points
                        if (value === '--') {
                            value = 0;
                        }
                        else if (value === 'NA') {
                            value = 0;
                        }
                        else if (value === '(s)') {
                            value = 0;
                        }
                        else if (value === 'W') {
                            value = 0;
                        }

                        // add record of current total electricity consumption
                        record.totalElectricityConsumption.push(value);
                    }
                }

// create a list of country names
                localities[record.Locality] = record;
                listOfLocalities.push(record.Locality);
                }
}
```

Sorry, formatting is not perfect as I had to take some stuff out to make the code more readable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Share the code that creates `localities[localityName].totalElectricityConsumption`. By the way, here is a hint: it **is** returning the max value, but not what you expect.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Edit has been made!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I'm not sure I quite understand your hint...it returns the expected max value for some datasets, but not all. Could you please clarify?

Comment: It returns the max value for **all** datasets. But it is the maximum *string*.

Answer (score 9):

As expected, `d3.max()` is indeed returning the maximum value... however, it is returning the maximum value among **strings**, not among numbers.

The explanation is that, by default, `d3.csv()` will load all the values as strings, even if they are numbers. Therefore, when you do:

```
var value = record[year];
```

`value` is a string, not a number. And in JavaScript the maximum for an array of strings is different from the maximum for an array of numbers. For instance, using numbers:

```js
var myArray = [1, 65, 9, 32, 42];
console.log(d3.max(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

That's the expected value. But look what happens if we use strings:

```js
var myArray = ["1", "65", "9", "32", "42"];
console.log(d3.max(myArray));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**: change your values to numbers:

```
var value = +record[year];
```

Comment: Just attempted to convert my `value` variable into a number using `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, and `Number()` individually and used the console to confirm that they were numbers. However, after I push it into my record, I don't notice any change.

Comment: In that case you have **another** problem. The issue with `d3.max()` is just that one I explained.

Comment: Yeah, what you said definitely makes sense. I knew it was an issue with the parsing from the get go. I think I actually just found my solution. Before running d3.max(), I make a new array and then use a loop to run through each value of my original array and reparse the values. After that, I push each value into the new array. Then I run THAT array through d3.max() and I am finally getting the correct value. I feel like I shouldn't have to do that, however.

Comment: @Lefty You can convert the values when you parse the CSV with a function that knows how to convert each row (by name). `var rowConverter = function(d) { return { Amount: parseFloat(d), Date: someDateParser(d) }; }; d3.csv("/path/file.csv", rowConverter, function(data) { // ... })`.